# Java Streams clone in C++

Tags: c++, java-8, stream

Is there something like the streams in Java 8 also in C++?
For Example, in Java you can iterate over a collection using streams like so:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
Arrays.stream(arr); // this returns a stream

// on these streams you can apply some functions like the filter function:

int evenArray[] = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(a -> { return a % 2 == 0; }).toArray();

// the result of filter is another stream. You can also collect to a new array after
```

So, is there something like this in C++? I really like this feature of Java and all I found was an article explaining, there wasn't.
I am hoping, that C++ maybe got an update that slipped by me.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)

Comment: I fear that you are trying to write C++ code by using Java as a model.  Doing that will more than likely 1) Produce buggy programs, 2) Produce inefficient programs, or 3) Produce programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Make that an answer.

Comment: Different languages have different ways of doing things. It's generally not a good ide to try direct translations. With that said, ranges (as already mentioned) are probably the closest analogue to Java streams, but they are still not exactly the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This might be true in general but not necessarily for specific features, and something like Java’s sequence streaming API is (a) very universally useful (and has found near-universal adoption), (b) not tied to a specific programming paradigm and (c) generally very close in spirit to (and indirectly inspired by!) C++’s STL sequence algorithms. It’s just that (unfortunately) Eric Niebler’s Ranges library appears to have quite serious issues that prevent it from being useful in practice in many situations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I generally agree, however if there is one thing that I liked about java it is this feature. It just feels better to use this than to write and call endless functions just to breeze through some elements. Also I heard somewhere that languages sometimes want you to think doing something that one way is bad, because they cant deliver that way of doing it. Would be sad if that was the case with C++, since C++ usually is very capable in that aspect :)

Comment: You can use [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). And you might want to use std::vector instead of a "C" style array (or std::array).  And to only loop over even numbers there is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view. Note that C++'s way of working is completely different from Java and you need to really make a distinction between passing objects and passing references to objects (copies or no copies)

Comment: @lorro I don't know anything about Java streams so I'm not confident it's a direct replacement.  I figured linking the OP to it at least lets them decide if it will work for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @NathanOliver, C++20 ranges come to the rescue.
If one wanted to first filter a `std::vector<int>`, then multiply ever element by 2, one could write:

```cpp
#include <ranges>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
namespace vi = std::ranges::views;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
namespace rn = std::ranges;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        std::vector<int> vec = { 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 4, 6 };                                                                                                                                                                                
        auto result = vec | vi::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; })                                                                                                                                                             
                          | vi::transform([](int i) { return i * 2; });                                                                                                                                          
                       // | rn::to<std::vector> // would collect to vector, but is C++23
        for (auto r : result)
                std::cout << r << " "; // output: 4 16 8 12                                       
        std::cout << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

However the output is a range, not a vector.
As far as I could find out, there was no standard way of converting back into a vector in C++20, however `std::ranges::to` was added in C++23. Up until then you need a workaround.